# How to translate "the extension is turned off" vs. "the extension is disabled"?

Tags: traduction, anglais, informatique

I'm faced with a difficulty in finding different words to distinguish the notion of "turned off" vs. "disabled" in the context of browser extensions.

The specific sentences are:

> The Chrome browser extension is turned off.

and

> The Chrome browser extension is disabled.

Normally I'd translate either of them by "désactivée", but how to say "turned off"?

Comment: I don't see an obvious difference between “turned off” and “disabled”. If someone told me a Chrome extension was “turned off”, I'd understand that the “Enabled” checkbox was unticked, same as “disabled”. What does “turned off” mean, how does it differ from “disabled”?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering the update, that made me think "disabled" is *stronger* than "turned off", in the sense that it's *easier* to turn on the extension than it is to enable it (you don't have to restart the browser). So in that case, i would translate "turned off" by **"désactivée"** (or "mise en veille" which corresponds to "standby mode") and "disabled" by **"éteinte"**.

But, if you choose **"mise en veille"** to translate "turned off", i think you can use both **"désactivée"** or "éteinte" for "disabled". And maybe "désactivée" is more common for the browser-extension context...

Comment: Considering the update in the question, would you still propose the same translation?

Comment: In this case the browser itself uses the word "désactivée" pour "disabled", so I'd like to keep my translation consistent with that and use another term for "turned off", which I haven't found in the browser (the text was given to me my the developpers). I'll probably have to use "mise en veille" in that case.

Comment: "mise en veille" is nice, but if you prefer a one-word translation you could try "endormie". Sounds maybe more like poetry than computer but why not :)

Answer (score 1):

Dans un contexte où il faut deux niveaux d'importance, j'aurais tendance à utiliser *arrêter* pour le plus temporaire, celui dont la cause est la volonté de l'utilisateur, celui qui suppose le plus que le fonctionnement est possible et *désactiver* pour l'autre.

Mais une telle nuance devrait être expliquée quelque part parce qu'elle n'est pas particulièrement standard.

Answer (score 1):

Pour *"turned off"* :
*"mis en veille"* et *"en veille"* me semblent convenable, mais *"suspendu"* est peut-être encore mieux.

> Mais une telle nuance devrait être expliquée quelque part parce qu'elle n'est pas particulièrement standard.

Je plussois.